docker-compose rabbitmq:3.8-management do not running
I am trying to run docker-compose rabbitmq but unable to do it
Here is the source code:
version: '3.8'

services:
  demo-rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    volumes:
      - demo-rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - demo-network

networks:
  demo-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  demo-rabbitmq-data:

When try to docker compose run by the command docker-compose up --build And I an getting this error:
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network 200-devops_demo-network       Created                                                                      0.5s 
 ✔ Container 200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  Created                                                                      1.3s 
Attaching to 200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:16.597 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:17.916 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:17.923 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:19.187 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:19.192 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:20.310 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:20.315 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:22.036 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:22.042 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:23.231 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:23.235 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:24.621 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:24.633 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:25.843 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:25.847 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:27.096 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:27.100 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:28.177 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:28.180 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:29.341 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | Distribution failed: {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :auth, {'Too short cookie string', [{:auth, :init_no_setcookie, 0, [file: 'auth.erl', line: 313]}, {:auth, :init, 1, [file: 'auth.erl', line: 165]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 2, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 423]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 390]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}}, {:child, 
:undefined, :net_sup_dynamic, {:erl_distribution, :start_link, [%{clean_halt: false, name: :"rabbitmqcli-496-rabbit@74e3e67bdb95", name_domain: :shortnames, net_tickintensity: 4, net_ticktime: 60, supervisor: :net_sup_dynamic}]}, :permanent, false, 1000, :supervisor, [:erl_distribution]}}
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | WARNING: 'docker-entrypoint.sh' generated/modified the RabbitMQ configuration file, which will no longer happen in 3.9 and later! (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/424)
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | Generated end result, for reference:
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | ------------------------------------
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | loopback_users.guest = false
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | listeners.tcp.default = 5672
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | ------------------------------------
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | Configuring logger redirection
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.838 [error] Too short cookie string
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.846 [error] 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.839 [error] Supervisor net_sup had child auth started with auth:start_link() at undefined exit with reason "Too short cookie string" in auth:init_no_setcookie/0 line 313 in context start_error
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.839 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.200.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: "Too short cookie string" in 
auth:init_no_setcookie/0 line 313
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | BOOT FAILED
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | ===========
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.867 [error] BOOT FAILED
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.868 [error] ===========
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.868 [error] Exception during startup:
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.869 [error] 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.869 [error]     supervisor:children_map/4 line 1250
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.869 [error]     supervisor:'-start_children/2-fun-0-'/3 line 384
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.870 [error]     supervisor:do_start_child/2 line 400
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.870 [error]     supervisor:do_start_child_i/3 line 414
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.870 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0 line 27
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.871 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0 line 111
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | Exception during startup:
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     supervisor:children_map/4 line 1250
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     supervisor:'-start_children/2-fun-0-'/3 line 384
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     supervisor:do_start_child/2 line 400
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     supervisor:do_start_child_i/3 line 414
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0 line 27
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0 line 111
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.871 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:setup/1 line 15
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:setup/1 line 15
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.891 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:duplicate_node_check/1 line 53
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.891 [error] error:{badmatch,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.892 [error]           {error,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.892 [error]               {{shutdown,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.892 [error]                    {failed_to_start_child,auth,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:duplicate_node_check/1 line 53
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | error:{badmatch,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |           {error,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |               {{shutdown,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                    {failed_to_start_child,auth,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                        {"Too short cookie string",
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                         [{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.893 [error]                        {"Too short cookie string",
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.893 [error]                         [{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.893 [error]                              [{file,"auth.erl"},{line,313}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.903 [error]                          {auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,165}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.903 [error]                          {gen_server,init_it,2,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.903 [error]                              [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,423}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.904 [error]                          {gen_server,init_it,6,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.904 [error]                              [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,390}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.904 [error]                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.904 [error]                              [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}}},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.905 [error]                {child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.905 [error]                    {erl_distribution,start_link,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.905 [error]                        [#{clean_halt => false,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.905 [error]                           name => rabbit_prelaunch_381@localhost,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.906 [error]                           name_domain => shortnames,net_tickintensity => 4,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.906 [error]                           net_ticktime => 60,supervisor => net_sup_dynamic}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.906 [error]                    permanent,false,1000,supervisor,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.906 [error]                    [erl_distribution]}}}}
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:39.907 [error]
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                              [{file,"auth.erl"},{line,313}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                          {auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,165}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                          {gen_server,init_it,2,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                              [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,423}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                          {gen_server,init_it,6,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                           name => rabbit_prelaunch_381@localhost,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                           name_domain => shortnames,net_tickintensity => 4,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                           net_ticktime => 60,supervisor => net_sup_dynamic}]},
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                    permanent,false,1000,supervisor,
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |                    [erl_distribution]}}}}
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:40.908 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Too short cookie string",[{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,313}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,165}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,423}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,390}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[#{clean_halt => false,name => rabbit_prelaunch_381@localhost,...}]},...}}}} in context start_error
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | 12:45:40.909 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.152.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{sprelaunch:run_prelaunch_firhutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Too short cookie string",[{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,[{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,313}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,165}]},{gen_server,init_i},{line,423}]},{gen_server,t,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,423}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,390}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_aundefined,net_sup_dynamic,{pply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[#{clean_halt rror
=> ...,...}]},...}}}}}},...} in application_master:init/4 line 142                                                         hutdown,{failed_to_start_ch
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunc,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,3h,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{\"Too short cookie sinit_it,6,[{file,"gen_servetring\",[{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,313}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,165}]},{gen_seerl_distribution,start_linkrver,init_it,2,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,423}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,390}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,226}]}]}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_lih,{{shutdown,{failed_to_stank,[#{clean_halt => false,name => rabbit_prelaunch_381@localhost,name_domain => shortnames,net_tickintensity => 4,net_ticktookie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"ime => 60,supervisor => net_sup_dynamic}]},permanent,false,1000,supervisor,[erl_distribution]}}}}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,s,{gen_server,init_it,6,[{fitart,[normal,[]]}}}"}                                                                                                      net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distri
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Too short cookie string",[{auth,init_no_setcookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,313}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,165}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,423}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,390}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[#{clean_halt => false,name => rabbit_prelaunch_381@localhost,name_domain => shortnames,net_tickintensity => 4,net_ticktime => 60,supervisor => net_sup_dynamic}]},permanent,false,1000,supervisor,[erl_distribution]}}}}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1  |
200-devops-demo-rabbitmq-1 exited with code 0

Several time I changed the rabbitmq versions, but getting the same error.
And again I re-install the docker, but problem is not solved.
Can you help in this case?

What is missing in the documentation? You'll likely have to count it yourself.

You should be as capable of counting them as well as anyone here. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. We're not a site for please read the documentation for me to get the information posts. And why do you need this information anyway? It's doubtful you'll ever need to use every single one that is available. Rather than wasting your time on useless trivia, spend it on something productive.

Hello stdunbar, your given references is not latest. This is the latest document https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/index.html, thank you for your effort

Hello Ken I like your advice

Given the large number of AWS services and the varying number of CLI commands for each service, it's difficult to provide an exact count of the total number of CLI AWS commands. However, a rough estimate would be in the range of several thousand CLI commands across all AWS services.
Specifically, considering the number of services and the typical number of CLI commands per service, the total number of CLI AWS commands is likely in the range of 3,000 to 5,000 or more.

Its helpful information, thank you @smac2020
